# Terminal says missing 1 required positional argument when I filled them all in

Tags: python

```
class Dish_Washer:

  def heat_water(self):
    print("Water is heating")

  def wash dishes(self):
    print("Dishes are washing")

  def open_door_malfunction(self):
    print("Door is open")    

  def start_cycle(self, is_on, door_closed):
    is_on = is_on
    door_closed = door_closed
    if door_closed == False:
      self.open_door_malfunction()
    elif is_on == True and door_closed == True:
      self.heat_water()
      self.wash_dishes()
 
 

dishwasher = Dish_Washer
dishwasher.start_cycle(True, True)
```

Terminal:

```
Dish_washer.start_cycle() missing 1 required positional argument: door_closed
```

I tried each function outside the `Dish_Washer` class and it worked. However when I put them in the class it output an error.

It should say:

```
Water is heating
Dishes are washing
```

Comment: `dishwasher = Dish_Washer` does **not** instantiate the class, merely creates an alias to it. Also note `and door_closed == True` is redundant given you're in an `elif` where the first condition was `door_closed == False` (better written as `not door_closed`).

Answer (score 2):

```
dishwasher = Dish_Washer()
```

You should use `()` create an object instead of the name of the class.
When you use your code, the first `True` goes to `self` because you didn't create the object by `dishwasher = Dish_Washer`.